# Twitter Sentiment Analysis - Remove bot duplication for more accurate results

Tags: python, tweepy, sentiment-analysis

Just to preface, this code is from a great guy on Github / Youtube:
https://github.com/the-javapocalypse/

I made some minor tweaks for my personal use.

One thing that has always stood between myself and sentiment analysis on twitter is the fact that so many bots posts exist. I figure if I cannot avoid the bots altogether, maybe I can just remove duplication to hedge the impact.

For example - "#bitcoin" or "#btc" - Bot accounts exist under many different handles posting the same exact tweet. It could say "It's going to the moon! Buy now #btc or forever regret it! Buy, buy, buy! Here's a link to my personal site [insert personal site url here]"

This would seem like a positive sentiment post. If 25 accounts post this 2 times per account, we have some inflation if I am only analyzing the recent 500 tweets containing "#btc"

So to my question:

1. What is an effective way to remove duplication before writing to the csv file? I was thinking of inputting a simple if statement and point to an array to check if it exists already. There is an issue with this. Say I input 1000 tweets to analyze. If 500 of these are duplication from bots, my 1000 tweet analysis just became a 501 tweet analysis. This leads to my next question
2. What is a way to include a check for duplication and if there is duplication add 1 each time to my total request for tweets to analyze. Example - I want to analyze 1000 tweets. Duplication was found one time, so there are 999 unique tweets to include in the analysis. I want the script to analyze one more to make it 1000 unique tweets (1001 tweets including the 1 duplicate)
3. Small change, but I think it would be effective to know how to remove all tweets with hyperlinks embedded. This would play into the objective of question 2 by compensating for dropping hyperlink tweets. Example - I want to analyze 1000 tweets. 500 of the 1000 have embedded URLs. The 500 are removed from the analysis. I am now down to 500 tweets. I still want 1000. Script needs to keep fetching non URL, non duplicates until 1000 unique non URL tweets have been accounted for.

See below for the entire script:

```
import tweepy
import csv
import re
from textblob import TextBlob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class SentimentAnalysis:

    def __init__(self):
        self.tweets = []
        self.tweetText = []

    def DownloadData(self):
        # authenticating
        consumerKey = ''
        consumerSecret = ''
        accessToken = ''
        accessTokenSecret = ''
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumerKey, consumerSecret)
        auth.set_access_token(accessToken, accessTokenSecret)
        api = tweepy.API(auth)

        # input for term to be searched and how many tweets to search
        searchTerm = input("Enter Keyword/Tag to search about: ")
        NoOfTerms = int(input("Enter how many tweets to search: "))

        # searching for tweets
        self.tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=searchTerm, lang="en").items(NoOfTerms)

        csvFile = open('result.csv', 'a')

        csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

        # creating some variables to store info
        polarity = 0
        positive = 0
        negative = 0
        neutral = 0

        # iterating through tweets fetched
        for tweet in self.tweets:
            # Append to temp so that we can store in csv later. I use encode UTF-8
            self.tweetText.append(self.cleanTweet(tweet.text).encode('utf-8'))
            analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
            # print(analysis.sentiment)  # print tweet's polarity
            polarity += analysis.sentiment.polarity  # adding up polarities

            if (analysis.sentiment.polarity == 0):  # adding reaction
                neutral += 1
            elif (analysis.sentiment.polarity > 0.0):
                positive += 1
            else:
                negative += 1

        csvWriter.writerow(self.tweetText)
        csvFile.close()

        # finding average of how people are reacting
        positive = self.percentage(positive, NoOfTerms)
        negative = self.percentage(negative, NoOfTerms)
        neutral = self.percentage(neutral, NoOfTerms)

        # finding average reaction
        polarity = polarity / NoOfTerms

        # printing out data
        print("How people are reacting on " + searchTerm +
              " by analyzing " + str(NoOfTerms) + " tweets.")
        print()
        print("General Report: ")

        if (polarity == 0):
            print("Neutral")
        elif (polarity > 0.0):
            print("Positive")
        else:
            print("Negative")

        print()
        print("Detailed Report: ")
        print(str(positive) + "% positive")
        print(str(negative) + "% negative")
        print(str(neutral) + "% neutral")

        self.plotPieChart(positive, negative, neutral, searchTerm, NoOfTerms)

    def cleanTweet(self, tweet):
        # Remove Links, Special Characters etc from tweet
        return ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t]) | (\w +:\ / \ / \S +)", " ", tweet).split())

    # function to calculate percentage
    def percentage(self, part, whole):
        temp = 100 * float(part) / float(whole)
        return format(temp, '.2f')

    def plotPieChart(self, positive, negative, neutral, searchTerm, noOfSearchTerms):
        labels = ['Positive [' + str(positive) + '%]', 'Neutral [' + str(neutral) + '%]',
                  'Negative [' + str(negative) + '%]']
        sizes = [positive, neutral, negative]
        colors = ['yellowgreen', 'gold', 'red']
        patches, texts = plt.pie(sizes, colors=colors, startangle=90)
        plt.legend(patches, labels, loc="best")
        plt.title('How people are reacting on ' + searchTerm +
                  ' by analyzing ' + str(noOfSearchTerms) + ' Tweets.')
        plt.axis('equal')
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sa = SentimentAnalysis()
    sa.DownloadData()
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Answer to your first question

You can remove duplicates by using this one liner.

```
self.tweets = list(set(self.tweets))
```

This will remove every duplicated tweet. Just in case if you want to see it working, here is a simple example

```
>>> tweets = ['this is a tweet', 'this is a tweet', 'Yet another Tweet', 'this is a tweet']
>>> print(tweets)
['this is a tweet', 'this is a tweet', 'Yet another Tweet', 'this is a tweet']
>>> tweets = list(set(tweets))
>>> print(tweets)
['this is a tweet', 'Yet another Tweet']
```

#### Answer to your second question

Since now you have already removed duplicates, you can get the number of removed tweets by taking the difference of `self.tweets` and `NoOfTerms`

```
tweets_to_further_scrape = NoOfTerms - self.tweets
```

Now you can scrape `tweets_to_further_scrape` number of tweets and repeat this process of removing duplication and scraping until you have found desired number of unique tweets.

#### Answer to your third question

When iterating tweets list, add this line to remove external links.

```
tweet.text = ' '.join([i for i in tweet.text.split() if 'http' not in i])
```

Hope this will help you out. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply keep a running count of the tweet instances using a `defaultdict`.  You may want to remove the web addresses as well, in case they are blasting out new shortened URLs.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def __init__(self):
    ...
    tweet_count = defaultdict(int)

def track_tweet(self, tweet):
    t = self.clean_tweet(tweet)
    self.tweet_count[t] += 1

def clean_tweet(self, tweet):
    t = tweet.lower()
    # any other tweet normalization happens here, such as dropping URLs
    return t

def DownloadData(self):
    ...
    for tweet in self.tweets:
        ...
        # add logic to check for number of repeats in the dictionary.
```